# AG-Grid cell template value change

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I am tinkering with **ag-grid** in Angular 1 mode and have come across a strange problem.  Using the tutorial, I have recreated the problem [in this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/20NVolND3F9SWSJXECd9?p=preview) which I am having in my more complex code.  You can see it by double clicking the "Athlete" column values.

Simply put, if you go in to edit mode on an editable column which has a template applied, the value will blank out.  It doesn't matter what you set it as, the binding appears to be broken.

For instance:

```
template: "<div ng-bind='data.athlete'></div>"
```

Will return something like:

```
<div>Michael Phelps</div>
```

But when you double click it to edit it, it will forever after return something like:

```
<div ng-bind='data.athlete'></div>
```

I suspect data.athlete is being unbound by the save, but I'm not sure how to correct that.  I'd really prefer not to have to create a value change handler for every column I plan to bind in.

The same happens if you use string interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`cellTemplate`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-template/index.php) use [`cellRenderer`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/index.php). It is much more useful and you can do a lot more with it. Here is your adjusted [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JorbjFAhUxUZjHDYAqqv?p=preview)

Comment: Ah.  This is great - thank you.  Do you know if ng-model will work similarly so I can bind this back to my data provider without having to do valueChangeHandler?  Or is there a better way to keep an angular model in sync with the grid's model?  `rowData = provider.getData()` maybe?

Comment: I am not that familiar with how angular and ag-grid share data, sorry

Comment: In case anyone comes back: if you specify `rowData = someProvider.getData()`, it will automatically keep your data models up to date when you change data on the grid.  Even if they're abstracted away several levels deep.  Note that rowData needs to be set to function.  `rowData = someProvider.data` will not work.  This is true for all angular data bindings and nothing to do with AG Grid.

Comment: hi @oooya, I set my rowData as null first, when my asyncrons call finished I set rowData like that: $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.RolePerData); however this behaviour my ng-model (binded data) does not shown as should be .